# Ruby on Rails - Search Query for words within the title

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, search, scope, filterrific

In my application I am doing a `scope/search` on `:title` for a *search/filter* of my records. The search itself works fine, only thing is that user need to write exactly the `title` & they can't search word within the `:title`.

*For instance If the `title` is:* **This search is cool**, user need to start the search and have the complete sentence: **This search** to search and they can't write **is cool** and get records that have **is cool** in the title.

*My `scope` looks like:*

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :search_query, lambda { |query|
    return nil  if query.blank?
    # condition query, parse into individual keywords
    terms = query.downcase.split(/\s+/)
    # replace "*" with "%" for wildcard searches,
    # append '%', remove duplicate '%'s
    terms = terms.map { |e|
      (e.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%')
    }
    # configure number of OR conditions for provision
    # of interpolation arguments. Adjust this if you
    # change the number of OR conditions.
    num_or_conditions = 1
    where(
        terms.map {
          or_clauses = [
              "LOWER(posts.title) LIKE ?"
          ].join(' OR ')
          "(#{ or_clauses })"
        }.join(' AND '),
        *terms.map { |e| [e] * num_or_conditions }.flatten
    )
  }
```

How can I make my `scope/query` so user can search words within the `title` and get records that has words they have searched for?

I tried with `ILIKE`, but then the search stop working *in development*, I think its because of `sqlite` can't have `ILIKE`, but in `production`the search worked but still can't search for words within titles.

When I use `LIKE`, the `sql` query was:

```
SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "posts" WHERE ((LOWER(posts.title) LIKE 'rails%')) LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
```

While when I used `ILIKE`, the query was:

```
SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "posts" WHERE ((LOWER(posts.title) ILIKE 'rails%')) LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count

SQLite3::SQLException: near "ILIKE": syntax error: SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "posts" WHERE ((LOWER(posts.title) ILIKE 'rails%')) LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
```

*ps: Im using `Filterrific gem`*

*I use `pg gem` for `Production ENV` & `sqlite3` for `Development ENV`*

Comment: a quick look says me, you should use ILIKE for pg and sqlite3

Comment: Thanks @marmeladze, I tried with `ILIKE `, but then the whole search doesn't work. Even what worked before.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form might be useful

Comment: @user6589814 *"then the whole search doesn't work. Even what worked before"* -- Huh?? Can you find out *what SQL was being generated before and after*? I don't understand how that could possibly have broken your code.

Comment: @TomLord I updated the question with the SQL query generated. It looks like `ILIKE` didn't work only in `Development ENV`, but in `Production ENV` has no problem, but I still can't search for words within titles even with `ILIKE` in `Production ENV`

Comment: This is growing into a "please debug my application" question, which is probably not appropriate for StackOverflow. The `ILIKE` error is quite obvious: This is legal syntax is Postgres, but not sqlite; I would suggest just using postgres locally. Your other issue is hard to debug without more information, but I suspect it's because you are searching for `rails%` instead of `%rails%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its described in this [w3schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp), `LIKE` works as:

```
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%' => Finds any values that starts with "a"
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%a' => Finds any values that ends with "a"
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%' => Finds any values that have "or" in any position
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '_r%' => Finds any values that have "r" in the second position
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a_%_%' =>  Finds any values that starts with "a" and are at least 3 characters in length
WHERE ContactName LIKE 'a%o' => Finds any values that starts with "a" and ends with "o"
```

I needed to change `(e.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%')`, **to:** `('%' + e.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%')` .

*When searching with `(e.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%')`, result would be `(LOWER(posts.title) ILIKE 'keyword%')`*, where as `('%' + e.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%')`, would give `(LOWER(posts.title) ILIKE '%keyword%')`